# Extract number from array in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I have a array which have certain elements. Each element have two char "BC" followed by a number 
e.g - "BC6"

I want to extract the number which is present and store in a different array.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);
my @band = ("BC1", "BC3");
foreach my $elem(@band)
{
    my @chars = split("", $elem);
    foreach my $ele (@chars) {
        looks_like_number($ele) ? 'push @band_array, $ele' : '';
    }
}
```

After execution @band_array should contain (1,3)

Can someone please tell what I'm doing wrong? I am new to perl and still learning

Comment: why dont u try to use regex

Comment: Do not put `'push @band_array, $ele' ` into single qoutes. It is a string in perl

Comment: @N.HariHaraSudhan Can you please tell me some link for regex which I can use. I havent use regex before

Comment: As for Perl documentation, http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html is a good start. All you need to do is grab numbers.

Comment: try this inside the for loop on each elemet of array `\d+`

Comment: i didnt used perl please go through this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_regular_expressions.htm)

Comment: You missing a semicolon. And if you run your program, you'll get a bunch of warnings after adding that semicolon in. Please either show us your _real code_ or at least try to run your stuff yourself.

Answer (score 3):

To do this with a regular expression, you need a very simple pattern. `/BC(\d)/` should be enough. The `BC` is literal. The `()` are a *capture group*. They save the match inside into a variable. The first group relates to `$1` in Perl. The `\d` is a *character group* for digits. That's `0-9` (and others, but that's not relevant here).

In your program, it would look like this.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
my @band = ('BC1', 'BC2');
my @numbers;
foreach my $elem (@band) {
    if ($elem =~ m/BC(\d)/) {
        push @numbers, $1;
    }
}

print Dumper @numbers;
```

This program prints:

```
$VAR1 = '1';
$VAR2 = '2';
```

Note that your code had several syntax errors. The main one is that you were using `@band = [ ... ]`, which gives you an array that contains one array reference. But your program assumed there were strings in that array.

Answer (score 1):

First, your array is an anonymous array reference; use () for a regular array.

Then, i would use grep to filter out the values into a new array

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @band = ("BC1", "BC3");   
my @band_array = grep {s/BC(\d+)/$1/} @band;

$"=" , ";   # make printing of array nicer
print "@band_array\n";  # print array
```

grep works by passing each element of an array in the code in { } , just like a sub routine. $_ for each value in the array is passed. If the code returns true then the value of $_ after the passing placed in the new array.

In this case the s/// regex returns true if a substitution is made e.g., the regex must match. Here is [link](https://perlmaven.com/filtering-values-with-perl-grep) for more info on grep

Comment: That's way better, thank you. However it's a bit around a few corners, isn't it? It only works because `grep` aliases the list elements, and the `s///` manipulates them. If the substitution was successful, it returns `1` and that triggers passing on the now altered (because of the alias) value. It gets the job done, but it's an unusual approach I would say. :-)

Comment: I would say this flexibility is this the beauty of perl and why we love it. Besides, if it was a m// then it would be exactly the same a linux grep :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just incase your naming contains characters other than `BC` this will exctract all numeric values from your list.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @band = ("AB1", "BC2", "CD3");
foreach my $str(@band) {
 $str =~ s/[^0-9]//g;
 print $str;
}
```